# Is belongs_to in Ecto and phoenix 1.3 gone?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Today I've installed phoenix 1.3 on my machine to test new features with command:

```
mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez
```

and created new phoenix project with

```
mix phx.new new_version
```

Then I generated a Blog context (or boundary) with a couple of models (Post and Comment) like this:

```
cd new_version
mix phx.gen.html Blog Post posts title body:text
mix phx.gen.html Blog Comment comments title body:text comment_post_id:references:blog_posts
```

After that I looked into comment model file and found that generated schema is different to what it looked like in phoenix 1.2

phoenix 1.3 Comment schema:

```
  schema "blog_comments" do
    field :body, :string
    field :title, :string
    field :comment_post_id, :id

    timestamps()
  end
```

Whereas in phoenix 1.2 Comment generated schema would look like this:

```
  schema "comments" do
    field :title, :string
    field :body, :string
    belongs_to :post, OldVersion.Post

    timestamps()
  end
```

You can see that belongs_to part of the schema is missing.

**So the question is how we should define model relationships (or schema associations) with new Ecto and Phoenix 1.3? Are the many_to_many, has_many, has_one, belongs_to all gone?**

I'm asking because I couldn't find such new format of schema nowhere, so if it's in the docs point me please.

Also I've noticed that phoenix generated migrations not into /priv/repo directory but into /test/new_version/priv/repo. Is that the desired behavior or should I change a config?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the generator to me..

Comment: This is still available from [`Ecto.Schema.belongs_to/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3). You have to replace `field :comment_post_id, :id` with `belongs_to :comment_post, Post`

Comment: Not sure if this is bug, or rather it has been discussed, and decided not to generate `belongs_to` so this should be handled manually by developer: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1842#issuecomment-260934357